# how to disallow disable open page in new window - cefsharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, cefsharp

[image: cefsharp opening two windows while navigating on google page but i want to open in one window]

I have tried a lot but couldnt make it work :(.
I want to have this second window open in same main window rather than new window.

I tried following but no luck, maybe i did something wrong as I am not good at coding :(

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/600

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/688

**https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194609/Capturing-a-pop-up-window-using-LifeSpanHandler-an**

can you please help me find solution so it opens in only Window no matter what button you click on any webpage

```html
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;


namespace Nysus
{

  
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            //Initialize
            Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com");
            this.pContainer.Controls.Add(chrome);
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
          
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            if (chrome.CanGoForward)
                chrome.Forward();
            if (chrome.CanGoBack)
                chrome.Back();
        }
       
        private void Form1_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }

        public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
        {
            browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(targetUrl);
            newBrowser = null;
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want is to force every target blank link to open in the same browser window, the LifeSpanHandler is the way to go (considering that you don't have access to the source HTML). The OnBeforePopup method works in this case but you added the method in a non-sense place. Create a new class that extends the `ILifeSpanHandler` class:

```
// MyCustomLifeSpanHandler.cs
using CefSharp;

public class MyCustomLifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    // Load new URL (when clicking a link with target=_blank) in the same frame
    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(targetUrl);
        newBrowser = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then replace the LifeSpanHandler with the custom one during the initialization of the browser (with your code would be):

```
ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    //Initialize
    Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com");

    // Implement Custom LifeSpanHandler
    chrome.LifeSpanHandler = new MyCustomLifeSpanHandler();
    // End Implement Custom LifeSpanHandler

    this.pContainer.Controls.Add(chrome);
    chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    if (chrome.CanGoForward)
        chrome.Forward();
    if (chrome.CanGoBack)
        chrome.Back();
}
```

And that should work. You can find the [whole example in this article here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1444/how-to-prevent-target-blank-links-from-opening-in-a-new-window-popups-in-cefsharp).

Comment: hi, i cant get it to work, please can you check the code and let me know my mistake? https://i.imgur.com/G3xmjK6.jpg

Comment: Your MyCustomLifeSpanHandler implementation needs to implement all the methods that are part of the http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_ILifeSpanHandler.htm interface.